# "gulp serve" returning "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, spfx, yo

Today is day one with SPFx and Gulp and Yo etc.

Trying a tutorial but it's blowing up with the following error:

```
mini-3:helloworld-webpart admin$ gulp serve
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:45:5
    at req_ (/playground/spfx/helloworld-webpart/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/playground/spfx/helloworld-webpart/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/playground/spfx/helloworld-webpart/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/playground/spfx/helloworld-webpart/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1
```

Here are all the steps I took so far:

https://pastebin.com/DC6XbPpq

As you can see when I tried to install the npm packages, I got a bunch of errors which, I'm not too sure how to resolve.
Also... I tried using version 12 of node, and version 10.  I wasn't able to install / execute 'yo'.  The only way I was able to get yo working was to use node 14.

Any suggestions would be helpful.  I'm very new to node, SPFx and npm.  I apologize in advance if I missed something simple.

**EDIT 1**

I accidentally got things to work.  I was reading up about gulp and tried just running 'gulp' instead of 'gulp serve'.  This is what I got:

```
    mini-3:hello-new-world admin$ gulp
    Build target: DEBUG
    [14:31:45] Using gulpfile /playground/spfx/hello-new-world/gulpfile.js
    [14:31:45] Starting 'default'...
    [14:31:45] Starting gulp
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
    [14:31:45] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 2.53 ms
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
    [14:31:45] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 48 ms
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'sass'...
    [14:31:45] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 23 ms
    [14:31:45] Finished subtask 'sass' after 112 ms
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
    [14:31:45] [tslint] tslint version: 5.12.1
    [14:31:45] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
    [14:31:45] [tsc] typescript version: 3.7.7
    [14:31:47] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 1.74 s
    [14:31:47] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 2.3 s
    [14:31:47] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
    [14:31:47] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 105 μs
    [14:31:47] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
    [14:31:47] Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 229 ms
    [14:31:47] Starting subtask 'webpack'...
    [14:31:48] Finished subtask 'webpack' after 673 ms
    [14:31:48] Finished 'default' after 3.38 s
    [14:31:49] ==================[ Finished ]==================
    [14:31:49] Project hello-new-world version:0.0.1
    [14:31:49] Build tools version:3.17.11
    [14:31:49] Node version:v14.17.3
    [14:31:49] Total duration:6.16 s
```

And now ... gulp serve works too.

I don't understand why.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Node 14 works fine with SPFx v1.12.1. Looks like you’re on macOS… the errors indicate you don’t have XCode installed, specifically the command line tools (*ref: “ gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!”*). Short story on that: they include some compilers used by some packages… when you install NPM packages, some require compilation once installed. They do it automatically so it’s transparent to you, but the tools need to be there. If you Google that error, you’ll find lots of hits on how to fix it, like this: https://medium.com/@mrjohnkilonzi/how-to-resolve-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-d0cf2b10a750

Why it worked the second time but not the first… err… can’t explain that part. It might be more that the first build failed, but the second attempt worked. When running `gulp` without specifying the task to run, it uses the default one. I *think* that’s the **build** task… but `gulp serve` runs the **build** task regardless.

I’d still fix the missing XCode CLI tools going forward… that’s not just an SPFx thing, but anything you use in the future that relies on NPM packages that will need it.

*BTW, in the future it helps if you say what version of SPFx you’re using. In this case, you can deduce it’s v1.12.1 from the pastebin, but that’s a key first question.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct version of gulp, that is updated to your npm version. To update npm run:

```
npm install
```

Then specify the gulp version, example:

```
npm install gulp@^4.0.2
```